# Use SqlQuery in EntityFramework to compose a real IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there a way to get SqlQuery or any other sql execution method to compose a model object and allow methods like Include to work?  I'm doing this (where view_products is an SQL table function):

```
var p = context.SqlQuery<Product>("select * from view_products(@param1)", new SqlParameter("param1", "somevalue"));
```

I want to then do this:

```
var list = p.Include(i => i.Inventories).ToList();
```

This gets me a DbRawSqlQuery.  This I can't "Include", because you can't do that on a DbRawSqlQuery.  So, I add an AsQueryable to the end, like:

```
var p = context.SqlQuery<Product>("select * from view_products(@param1)", new SqlParameter("param1", "somevalue")).AsQueryable<Product>();
```

But, I understand this is really giving me an IEnumerable, so the .Include doesn't yield any results.

I'm looking for suggestions on another way to do this where I get my Products from the SQL function and then load in their related Inventory objects so that I have an object graph.  Thanks!

Comment: Just right the query with the where clause two join the two tables. And select * from the joined table as navigation property name

Comment: @Brandon Seydel, that would get me back the data I want, but not fill in the object graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlQuery` poses problems some of which I wasn't yet aware of.

#### No Include

You correctly explain why `Include` doesn't have any effect after you convert an `IEnumerable` to an `IQueryable`. `Include` extends an expression, and an `IEnumerable` doesn't have an expression (and doesn't magically get one after converting it to `IQueryable`).

#### No lazy loading without attaching

So you end up having a list of `Product`s not attached to the context and *not capable of lazy loading*. You have to attach the `Product`s to the context explicitly (e.g. by setting their state to `Unchanged`) to make them lazy loading.

This is something I just found out and which is odd. The entities are materialized as proxy objects, but, contrary to detached entities that are fetched by `DbSet.AsNoTracking()`, they don't display lazy loading. I think it's a bug and I reported it.

But lazy loading causes the n + 1 query anti-pattern: queries that fetch Inventory objects for each Product separately. So it's not the best way to get your object graph.

#### No relationship fixup

So what you really want is load all Inventory objects that belong to these products in one shot and let *relationship fixup* do its job (i.e. EF auto-fills all `Product.Inventories` collections):

```
context.Inventories.Where(i => productIds.Contains(i.ProductId)).Load();
```

...where `productIds` is a list of procuct Ids in `p`.

But relationship fixup only works for attached entities, so again, you'll have to change their state to `Unchanged` explicitly. If you do that, you're ready to go... except you aren't.

Again there's a difference with detached entities fetched by `DbSet.AsNoTracking()`. The latter respond to relationship fixup, the ones from `SqlQuery` don't!

#### (Rather) elaborate solution

So what's left is: load the related `Inventory` objects as show above and fill the `Product.Inventories` collections yourself:

```
var query = from product in p
            join inv context.Inventories.Local
                on product.ProductId equals inv.ProductId
                into inventories
            select new { product, inventories }
foreach(var anon in query)
{
    anon.product.Inventories = anon.inventories.ToList();
}
```

Of course this is all quite unsatisfactory.

Comment: I think this result is the best that can be hoped for at this time.  I'm turning my attention to getting rid of the SQL table function and doing it all in EF queries.  Thanks for the suggestions!