# Using inline sql with entity frame work and c#

Tags: sql, entity-framework

We are having som performance issue with EF and I want to try rewrite a query to inline sql. However I am having some difficulties, it is probably just a noob issue.

Lets say I have 3 classes: License, GroupLicense and Product

```
    public class License
{
//stuff
Product MyProduct{get;set}
}

public class GroupLicense:License
{
// more stuff
}

public class Product
{
//product info stuff
}
```

Now I need to fetch some Grouplicenses depending on some requirements. However doing it with the datacontext and linq takes 2 minutes. 
Something similar to this

```
var institutionLicenses = db.GroupLicenses
            .Include(lic => lic.Product).Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.Product.Id) && x.LicenseStatus == StatusEnum.Active).ToList();
```

I want to do the same query using inline sql similar to this: I join the tables so all the primitive fields are okay.

```
 var gl = db.Database.SqlQuery<GroupLicense>("select * from GroupLicense as g left join Licenses on g.Id =Licenses.Id").ToList();
```

(It is just example code - I know it is not working :))

However when executing, The base product property on License is null, all the primitive fields are there.

What do I need to change in my sql statement to make it work?

Comment: I guess `productIds` may have a large size so that the query will become very slow. I don't think you can improve this much by using raw sql query. Technically you still need to build up the `IN` clause, pass in the list of `productIds` which I believe is also limited in size. Your sql query is in fact not some kind of equivalent to what the linq query does. I would stick to the linq query, if possible please let us know about the sizes of your entities (including the `productIds`).

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31773014/861716

Comment: How many items does `productIds` contain?

Comment: It Can hold to a max of 50